# Trigger - insert into @table select from inserted and execute a procedure if @@rowcount > 0 from @table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, rowcount

I have a trigger on TableA on after insert, update.  On insert the information is inserted in a table variable when the condition is right, if something is recovered from the select, a procedure is executed.

If `@ds` is null, the procedure is not executed. Any suggestions?

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
....
SET @dif = (SELECT ISNULL(COUNT(*), 0) FROM @ds); 

IF @dif > 0...
```

Thanks!

```
CREATE TRIGGER t_tablaA
ON tablaA
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ds TABLE (d VARCHAR(50));
    @who VARCHAR(MAX);

    INSERT INTO @ds
        SELECT p.email
        FROM inserted
        INNER JOIN personel p ON inserted.user = p.user

    IF @@rowcount > 0
       SELECT @who = COALESCE(@who , '')  + d + '; ' 
       FROM @ds

    EXECUTE sendEmailTo(@who);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing `BEGIN .. END`:

```
if @@rowcount > 0
BEGIN
 select @who = COALESCE(@who , '')  + d + '; ' FROM @ds;
 execute sendEmailTo(@who);
END;
```

or:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @ds)
BEGIN
 select @who = COALESCE(@who , '')  + d + '; ' FROM @ds;
 execute sendEmailTo(@who);
END;
```

---

Be aware that [`STRING_AGG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) emulation using variable `@who = COALESCE(@who , '')` may lead to undefined behaviour(especially when `ORDER BY` is used).

Another thing: sending email from trigger may lead to performance problems. Triggers should do "simple" actions and do not access external systems.